# No error getting while compiling spring project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat8, intellij-15

I am new to spring development ,while compiling pre-developed code(setup all the necessary tools).it gives me no error but not run on the browser.can not understand what the problem is?.
Ideaspring plugin also not enabling

.[image: error png]

**using intellij 15.02,tomcat 8**

> Localhost log

```
24-Dec-2015 16:29:39.181 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
24-Dec-2015 16:29:39.210 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
24-Dec-2015 16:29:40.119 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/root-context.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> **pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.triologysoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>trigga</artifactId>
    <name>trigga</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.1</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <scala.version>2.10.1</scala.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>repo.springsource.org.release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
            <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/master/releases/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
     <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fernandospr</groupId>
            <artifactId>javapns-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javapns</groupId>
            <artifactId>javapns</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>gcm-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.p12</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/no-portrait.png</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/META-INF/persistence.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>version.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>version.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.p12</include>
                    <include>**/log4j.xml</include>
                    <include>**/no-portrait.png</include>
                    <include>**/META-INF/persistence.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tree</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>tree</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputFile>src/main/resources/mavenDependencies.txt</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>adam-w-dev</id>
            <name>adam-w-dev-releases</name>
            <url>http://trident-build:8081/artifactory/trident</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>adam-w-dev</id>
            <name>adam-w-dev-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://trident-build:8081/artifactory/trident</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

**catalina log**

```
24-Dec-2015 13:25:46.884 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

> Message make log

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_65 to compile java sources
Information:Module "trigga" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:24/12/15 1:25 PM - Compilation completed successfully with 10 warnings in 5s 389ms
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor': class file for org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor not found
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor'
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/main/java/com/triologysoftware/services/EmailService.java
Warning:(189, 82) java: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
  cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
  cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
Warning:(193, 146) java: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
  cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
  cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/main/java/com/triologysoftware/dto/MobileDeviceDto.java
Warning:(30, 21) java: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
  cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
  cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/main/java/com/triologysoftware/services/security/SecurityUtil.java
Warning:(77, 89) java: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
  cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
  cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/main/java/com/triologysoftware/services/security/PropertyManager.java
Information:java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/test/java/com/triologysoftware/services/GoogleCloudMessengerTest.java
Warning:(9, 52) java: org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration in org.springframework.test.context.transaction has been deprecated
Warning:(20, 2) java: org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration in org.springframework.test.context.transaction has been deprecated
/home/canopus/AndroidStudioProjects/TRIGGA/trigga/src/test/java/com/triologysoftware/services/ApplePushNotifierTest.java
Warning:(11, 52) java: org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration in org.springframework.test.context.transaction has been deprecated
Warning:(21, 2) java: org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration in org.springframework.test.context.transaction has been deprecated
```

Comment: You didn't paste the most important part of the stack trace: the beginning, which contains the exception type and its error message. But it seems you have an invalid xml file.

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: You still haven't posted the beginning of the stack trace. But as I said, it's an xml parsing problem. Specifically, an xml related to spring security.

Comment: As @JBNizet said, the `root-context.xml` most likely references an older version of that xsd which is incompatible with your library newer version.